# merger is happening in our customer. Now, we have to update the user details in our app(db) on PROD. But how to test it(proc) before going into prod

Tags: oracle12c, banking, onlinebanking, core-banking

2 banks merger is happening for our client. We have to change the data for users in our database. I have created a procedure to change the data in the respective tables. But before going to PROD, how can we test the procedure on the testing environment.
Problems here are -

1. we are having a file with the old account numbers and new account numbers for PROD.
2. But in the testing environment, we do not have data.
3. We can not have a staging environment with the prod data to test this.

Do someone have any idea, how to achieve this?

Comment: Fill test database with mock data then run the test in the testing environment and next for production environment, create test account in production and run the procedure for that account specifically

Comment: *we are having a file with the old account numbers and new account numbers for PROD* Use the same file to load the data in test database.